# How can I make automatize fetchall() calling in pyodbc without exception handling?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I want to do automatic results fetching after every **pyodbc** query. In usual situation `cursor.fetchall()` calling raises a `ProgrammingError` exception if no SQL has been executed or if it did not return a result set (e.g. was not a SELECT statement). I want to do something like this:

```
def execute(query, data):
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    cursor.commit()
    try:
      result = cursor.fetchall()
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
      result =  None
    return result
```

Is there some way to make it possible without using exception handling (it works too slow if it used)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that might work for you, with a list of samples queries to run:

```
sql_to_run = [
    "SELECT 10000",
    "SELECT 2 + 2",
    "",
    "SELECT 'HELLO WORLD'",
]

for sql in sql_to_run:
    rows = cursor.execute(sql)

    if cursor.rowcount:
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
```

Output:

```
(10000, )
(4, )
('HELLO WORLD', )
```

Will that do the trick? Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I've tried your code and found out that my `cursor.rowcount` equals **-1** when there are a results to fetch and different number when there aren't. It's kinda strange (according to the documentation, it should work other way round), but it solved my problem anyway.

Comment: Just found out, that it is possible to use `cursor.description` attribute (which is `None` when there are no results) in cases when `cursor.rowcount` is equal to wrong value for some reasons.